# mongoose upsert silently failling

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a question about the way I am using the "upsert" query on mongoose. For some reason for a particular model it does not insert a new model even when upsert is true. It also doesn't send out an error telling me why it didn't update. It just returns numAffected=0, here is my current method

```
query = {gatewayId:req.body.gatewayId};
body  = {$push:{xbees:{$each: req.body.xbees}},
          "$setOnInsert":{address:req.body.address}};
options = [{upsert:true},{runValidators:true}]
GatewayData.update(query,body,options,function(err,numAffected,rawResposne){
    if (err) return next(err);
        if(numAffected == 0){
          console.log("ohno!");
    }
});;
```

Here is a copy of the model for reference

```
    var xbeeMapping = new mongoose.Schema({
       ...
    });

    var GatewayData = new mongoose.Schema({

        address:       {type: String, uppercase:true, required:true},
        gatewayId:     {type: String, match : validators.gateway_matcher, required: true},
        timestamp:     {type: Date,   default: Date.now},
        panID:         {type: String, uppercase:true},
        radThreshold:  {type: Number, default:30},
        roomThreshold: {type: Number, default:22.22},
        radCritical:   {type: Number, default:15},
        roomCritical:  {type: Number, default:19.5},

        xbees:[xbeeMapping] 

    });

    GatewayData.index({gatewayId:1});

module.exports = mongoose.model('GatewayData', GatewayData);
```

Note that this works properly when updating just not when inserting. Also im sorry if this is too wordy and please tell me if I should cut out my schema from the question.

Comment: what do you get from mongoose if you enable debugging?

Comment: Mongoose: gatewaydatas.update({ gatewayId: '00000000-00000000-00409DFF-FFFFFFFD' }) { '$push': { xbees: { '$each': [ { serialNumber: '40AC1233', roomNumber: 'LR', xbeeAddress: 'NODE_[40:AC:12:33]!', _id: ObjectId("55563d50f9c72ca75c15612c")
 } ] } }, '$setOnInsert': { address: 'Stephens' } } {}

Comment: I found the problem "options" is supposed to be an object, not an array!!! Thanks for telling me to turn on debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kevin B mentioned in the comments to turn on debugging.
I did and found the following:

```
Mongoose: gatewaydatas.update({
     gatewayId: '00000000-00000000-00409DFF-FFFFFFFD' }) 
     { '$push':
         { xbees: 
               { '$each': 
           [ { serialNumber: '40AC1233', 
               roomNumber: 'LR', xbeeAddress: 
                 'NODE_[40:AC:12:33]!', 
                _id: ObjectId("55563d50f9c72ca75c15612c") } ] } },         
     '$setOnInsert': { address: 'Stephens' } } {} –
```

The options were not being read properly!!

The correct format for options is

```
  options = {upsert:true, runValidators:true}
```

not

```
  options = [{upsert:true},{runValidators:true}]
```